# WeaklyConnectedGraphQ evaluates to False. Is this the expected result?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Take the simple graph `{1->2, 2->3, 3->1}`:

```
TreePlot[{1->2,2->3,3->1}]
```

[image: triangle]

I would expect that `WeaklyConnectedGrapghQ[{1->2,2->3,3->1}]` evaluates to `True`, but in fact I get `False`, so I was wondering if maybe my concept of connectet graph is wrong. Is this graph (weakly) connected or *Mathematica* is right and the correct output is `False`?.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, all functions ending in `Q` will return either `True` or `False`, but nothing else.

You can think of `WeaklyConnectedGraphQ` as testing that it's argument *is a graph* and that *it is weakly connected*.

`{1->2,2->3,3->1}` *is not a graph*, it is a list of rules.  Thus `WeaklyConnectedGraphQ` returns `False`.

`g = Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1}]` creates a graph from the rule list. `WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[g]` returns `True`.

Comment: This is it, thank you.